# Ubuntu accessibility software for Parkinsons disease

Tags: software-recommendation, accessibility

I have a relative suffering with this condition. They are often unable to enunciate words and their hands and arms shake during more extreme episodes.

I remember reading about software such as [Dasher](http://www.inference.org.uk/dasher/), which is available for Ubuntu. Are there any other applications that Ask Ubuntu members have found useful for sufferers of Parkinson's disease? The goal would be to help them communicate.

**Edit**: The goal is to help them communicate with people around them rather than help them do tasks on the computer.

Comment: A couple on this page, but you have to check them out.  https://alternativeto.net/software/dasher/

Comment: Start out with the [community help page on Accessibility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility).  The best set ups I have seen are tailored to the individual's abilities - usually a combination of shortcuts and different input devices - some people are better with trackballs - touch pad etc and there are some input devices out there that are made specifically for people with dexterity difficulties

Comment: Not specific to any particular disability, but AutoKey can provide desktop automation so that a particular phrase or hotkey can trigger arbitrarily complex desktop activities including keypresses and mouse movements with clicks. Once tailored to an individual's needs, this could greatly reduce the need for user input for common tasks. https://github.com/autokey/autokey

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks. I'll update my question to mention that I'm not looking to help them do comuter tasks, but to communicate with people around them. Maybe Dasher + text-to-speech can provide a solution.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers could you create an answer yourself when you have a list of programs? Just a link to the software center and a discription would be enough. Then we have a good answer that will be a good starter for other users.

Comment: @Rinzwind if I find anything suitable, yes absolutely. But as I say, applications that make computing tasks more accesible are not what I'm looking for. Something to help someone say "yes", "no", things like that, are what I need.

Comment: Just to update this finally and say that we never did find a workable technological solution to this. That was partly due to our situation and other people involved so if you are in the same position we were there may still be a solution out there.

Comment: Due to nature of the issue, It is may be hard even to find info about available solutions (proprietary, gratis/paid, open, free).
    Solution expected to be software only or embedded (SW+HW), If it can be linked to Ubuntu, it is a possible solution.
    From: specialized companies & groups, labs, university & hospital research ... . I raised a bounty to draw attention.

Comment: That's very kind @user.dz. Our parkinsons sufferer has since passed away, but I still run Ubuntu and can compile a list, if more information comes this way.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers. You are welcome, May God have mercy on him/her and let rest in peace. Myself want to see such list, It is the age of Open VC, Open AI libs, Xbox Kinect,... beside TTS,Smart phones,...

Comment: @TenLeftFingers, there are two other opensource projects but currently build only for Windows (.NET). They seem more promising if ported to Linux. http://www.optikey.org/ & https://precisiongazemouse.org/ both have informative github projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### eViacam

[Enable Viacam (eViacam)](https://eviacam.crea-si.com/) is a mouse replacement software that moves the pointer as you move your head.

- Support: MS Windows, GNU/Linux
- License: GNU/GPL3
- Package: Already in repository, install with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install eviacam
  ```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!